# Latex markdown package -- tables

Tags: tables, markdown

I thought I'd hit the jackpot when I found the `markdown` package:

https://ctan.org/pkg/markdown

But can some kind guru tell me if it supports tables and, if so, how to format them in markdown (*.md) files?

Comment: Have you looked through the documentation on the page you linked?  It mentions tables.  I don't see a mention of including the content of a file.

Comment: @Lloyd a table example straight from the documentation is added below

Answer (score 1):

LATEX Example

Using a text editor, create a text document named `table.csv` with the following content:

```
Name,Surname,Born
Albert,Einstein,1879
Marie,Curie,1867
Thomas,Edison,1847
```

Create also a text document named language-map.json with the following content:

```
{
  "tex": "LaTeX"
}
```

Create also a text document named code.tex with the following content:

This is an example code listing in \LaTeX.
Create also a text document named `part.md` with the following content:

This is a ***transcluded markdown document***.
Create also a text document named document.tex with the following content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[contentBlocks]{markdown}
\markdownSetup{
  contentBlocksLanguageMap = {language-map.json},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
/table.csv  (An example table)
/code.tex   (An example code listing)
/part.md    (A file transclusion example)
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

Next, invoke LuaTeX from the terminal:

```
lualatex --shell-escape document.tex
```

A PDF document named document.pdf should be produced and contain the following text:

```
Name    Surname Born
Albert  Einstein    1879
Marie   Curie   1867
Thomas  Edison  1847
Table 1: An example table
```

This is an example code listing in \LaTeX.
This is a transcluded markdown document.

Comment: Thank you js bibra.

Comment: I did look at this doc and try the example, but couldn’t get it to work—possibly because I used memoir rather than article. But what I need is to include tables in markdown-tagged book manuscripts. It’s not clear to me how to do this from the doc.